# Stop while loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I want to create a shell script to run some Command on the terminal but the script won't stop until i finish using terminal

example:

```
while true ; do 
    echo -e "type 1 or 2 : "
    read answer 

    case "$answer" in 
        1 )
            xfce4-terminal -e "sudo apt-get update"
            ;;
        2 )
            xfce4-terminal -e "sudo apt-get install firefox"
        ;;
    esac 
done
```

I want the while loop to stop and wait until the option 1 finishes and then continue.

Comment: I suggest: `help break`

Comment: i want the while loop `wait` not `stop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try an additional while loop that basically listens for that command to end?

```
case "$answer" in 
    1 )
    xfce4-terminal -e "sudo apt-get update"
    while [[ $(ps -elf | grep -v "grep" | grep -c "apt-get update") != "0" ]] ; do
      sleep 2
    done   
    ;;
2 )
    xfce4-terminal -e "sudo apt-get install firefox"
    ;;
esac
```

Here is an answer to your question from the comments:

```
while [[ $(find /var/cache/apt/archives -type f -name "*.deb") != "" ]] ; do
  sleep 1
done
```

This will search the /var/cache/apt/archives for any file names that end in .deb and wait for one second before searching again. Once no files are found, the while loop will finish.

Comment: tunx is worlk with `sudo apt-get update` but what about `sudo rm -vf /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb`

Comment: Not sure what you meant to say by tunx is worlk?

Comment: ahh gotcha. Hmm that next one you would have to just how you search. Give me one sec and I will provide another way for the "rm" way.

Comment: I'm so happy that there is people like you guys here in morocco i don't know lot's of people use Linux and so hard to get help ; that's why thank's you guys

Comment: @zakariagatter I updated my answer above to include a section showing a while loop that will search a directory for those flies and wait until those files are removed.

Comment: No problem at all Zakaria, happy to help :)

Comment: And all .deb files are no longer in that directory?

Comment: I'm not near my Linux computer right now but as soon as I am I will properly test it and get back to you

Comment: Testing this on my computer and everything ran smoothly. Are you sure there are no .deb files in that location?

Comment: Thank you im going to try it again